# He, she, it with animals

Tags: grammatical-gender, animals

When I want to write the story about little puppy, I have found on the street, should I use it or other gender?

Comment: For the most part humans invest pet animals with a lot of human qualities and treat them more or less as people. This the most frequent pronouns for dogs are the (appropriate) gendered ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sex of the animal is known 'him/her' is used. But if it is unknown i.e due to infancy ; 'it' is used.